# SQLAlchemy. Как обновить значение JSON в MySQL(Mariadb 10.2)?

Tags: json, sqlalchemy

Пытаюсь обновить значение в JSON, БД MySQL.

```
class Queue(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'queue'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    queue = Column(JSON)
```

Добавляю новую строку

```
q = Queue(queue={"10": {"first": 1, "second": 1}})
session.add(q)
session.commit()
```

Все добавляется и отображается в БД.
Следующим шагом пытаюсь исправить значение second

```
r = session.query(Queue).filter(Queue.id == 1).one()
r.queue
{"10": {"first": 1, "second": 1}}
r.queue['10']['second'] = 2
r.queue
{"10": {"first": 1, "second": 2}}
```

Значение изменилось локально, коммит и ...

```
sessin.commit()
r = session.query(Queue).filter(Queue.id == 1).one()
r.queue
{"10": {"first": 1, "second": 1}}
```

В БД ничего не изменилось.
Каким образом поменять значение в JSON используя SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алхимия не отслеживает запутанную структуру JSON данных, поэтому ей нужно явно указать, что они поменялись:

```
r = session.query(Queue).filter(Queue.id == 1).one()
r.queue
{"10": {"first": 1, "second": 1}}
r.queue['10']['second'] = 2
r.queue
{"10": {"first": 1, "second": 2}}

# указываем что не струкрирурованные данные изменились
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import flag_modified
flag_modified(r, "queue")

# после коммита данные должны поменяться
```